# Confusion about "enabled" parameter for bicep code to deploy function app in Azure

Tags: azure-functions, azure-bicep

When deploying a function app using bicep code - is it necessary to include the "enabled" parameter and set it to true for the function app to work or can you just leave it out (if it's enabled by default)? Link to documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/sites?pivots=deployment-language-bicep

Comment: Have you tried any code?

Answer (score 0):

[Site properities of Function App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/sites?pivots=deployment-language-bicep#siteproperties).

***Set "enabled" parameter to `true` if you want to enable the function App. Otherwise, it will set to the default value which is `false`. If you are not enabling it to `true`then the function App won't run and shows offline.***

*Modify the properities as shown:*

```
  properties: {
    enabled: true
    httpsOnly: true
  }
```

*Try below code to deploy a function app in bicep:*

```
param appName string = '<appname>'
param storageAccountType string = 'Standard_LRS'

param location string = resourceGroup().location


param appInsightsLocation string

param runtime string = 'dotnet'

var functionAppName = <appName>
var hostingPlanName = <appName>
var applicationInsightsName = <appName>
var storageAccountName = '<storageaccountName>'
var functionWorkerRuntime = dotnet

resource storageAccount 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2021-08-01' = {
  name: <storageAccountName>
  location: location
  sku: {
    name: storageAccountType
  }
  kind: 'Storage'
}

resource hostingPlan 'Microsoft.Web/serverfarms@2021-03-01' = {
  name: <hostingPlanName>
  location: location
  sku: {
    name: 'Y1'
    tier: 'Dynamic'
  }
  properties: {}
}

resource functionApp 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2021-03-01' = {
  name: functionAppName
  location: location
  kind: 'functionapp'
  identity: {
    type: 'SystemAssigned'
  }
  properties: {
    serverFarmId: hostingPlan.id
    enabled : true
    siteConfig: {
      appSettings: [
        {
          name: 'AzureWebJobsStorage'
          value: 'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=${storageAccountName};EndpointSuffix=${environment().suffixes.storage};AccountKey=${storageAccount.listKeys().keys[0].value}'
        }
        {
          name: 'WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING'
          value: 'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=${storageAccountName};EndpointSuffix=${environment().suffixes.storage};AccountKey=${storageAccount.listKeys().keys[0].value}'
        }
        {
          name: 'FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION'
          value: '~3'
        }
        {
          name: 'WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION'
          value: '~10'
        }
        {
          name: 'APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY'
          value: applicationInsights.properties.InstrumentationKey
        }
        {
          name: 'FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME'
          value: dotnet
        }
      ]
      ftpsState: 'FtpsOnly'
      minTlsVersion: '1.2'
    }
    httpsOnly: true
  }
}

resource applicationInsights 'Microsoft.Insights/components@2020-02-02' = {
  name: applicationInsightsName
  location: appInsightsLocation
  kind: 'web'
  properties: {
    Application_Type: 'web'
    Request_Source: 'rest'
  }
}
```

***Output:***

[image]

***Deployed successfully in Portal:***

[image]

Refer [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-first-function-bicep?tabs=CLI) for a bicep template.